# Typescript Generic vs Union

Tags: typescript

If i define function type with parameter like `value: string | number`, I can define function (value: string) => null of that type. And typescript don't show any warnings.

But if I define function type with generic parameter `<T extends string | number>(value: T)`, then typescript will show error.

Could someone explain this behaviour?

code sample

```js
type OnChangeUnion = (value: string | number) => void;

type OnChangeGeneric = <T extends string | number>(value: T) => void;

const handleChange = (value: string) => null;

const onChange: OnChangeGeneric = handleChange;
const onChangeA: OnChangeUnion = handleChange;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20OnChangeUnion%20%3D%20(value%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%0Atype%20OnChangeGeneric%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20string%20%7C%20number%3E(value%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%0Aconst%20handleChange%20%3D%20(value%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0A%0Aconst%20onChange%3A%20OnChangeGeneric%20%3D%20handleChange%3B%0Aconst%20onChangeA%3A%20OnChangeUnion%20%3D%20handleChange%3B)

Comment: Tbh if you enable all checks (see "Options" on the playground) you see that both assignments fail.

Comment: They are both bad assignments... both `OnChangeUnion` and `OnChangeGeneric` are function types which *must* accept a `string | number` argument.  But `handleChange` only accepts a `string` argument, so it is neither an `OnChangeUnion` nor an `OnChangeGeneric`.

Answer (score 0):

For the Generic example, your notation is just slightly off:

```
type OnChangeGeneric<T extends string | number> = (value: T) => void;
const handleChange = (value: string) => null;
const onChange: OnChangeGeneric<string> = handleChange;
```

The Union example will throw an actual compiler error (as noted by @zerkms), as `handleChange` only accepts a `string`, which is not compatible with `string | number`.

Comment: I can't tell if the notation is off, or if the OP is just confused about what the original `OnChangeGeneric` type was supposed to do.